# Assigning elements to layout.children in an update() callback function messes up the title of one child and the position of another

Tags: bokeh

I have a small bokeh application, consisting of inputs, a bar chart and a table. When the user selects a value from the inputs the chart and table are redrawn, based on the new data and the layout.children are replaced accordingly. The problem is that when the page is updated the bar chart title is messed up, as is the position of the table.

When it updates I print the length of the children in the first row. It is two each time, so it is not adding more children when I replace them in the update() function.

Here is the relevant code:

```
income = Select(title="Income Tier", options=sorted(income_map.keys()), 
value="All")
age = Select(title="Age", options=sorted(age_map.keys()), value="All")
gender = Select(title="Gender", options=sorted(gender_map.keys()), 
value="All")
relationship = Select(title="Relationship", 
options=sorted(relationship_map.keys()), value="All")
education = Select(title="Education", 
options=sorted(education_map.keys()), value="All")
user_interests = Select(title="User Interests", 
options=sorted(user_interests_map.keys()), value="All")

def update():
    update_p1()
    update_p2()

def update_p1():
    global awareness_data_copy
    global income
    global age
    global gender
    global relationship
    global education
    global graph_data
    global layout
    awareness_data_copy = awareness_data
    if income.value != 'All':
        awareness_data_copy = 
        awareness_data_copy.loc[(awareness_data_copy['income_tier'] == 
    income.value)]
    if age.value != 'All':
        awareness_data_copy = 
        awareness_data_copy.loc[(awareness_data_copy['age'] == 
        age.value)]
    if gender.value != 'All':
        awareness_data_copy = 
        awareness_data_copy.loc[(awareness_data_copy['gender'] == 
        gender.value)]
    if relationship.value != 'All':
        awareness_data_copy = 
        awareness_data_copy.loc[(awareness_data_copy 
        ['relationship_label'] == relationship.value)]
    if education.value != 'All':
        awareness_data_copy = 
        awareness_data_copy.loc[(awareness_data_copy['education_label'] 
        == education.value)]
    if user_interests.value != 'All':
        awareness_data_copy = 
        awareness_data_copy.loc[(awareness_data_copy[education.value] 
        != None)]
    for key, value in graph_data['values'].items():
        column_awareness_data_copy = awareness_data_copy
        if awareness_data_copy['product'].count() > 0:
            column_awareness_data_copy = 
            column_awareness_data_copy.loc[awareness_data_copy 
            [answer_field] == key]
            graph_data['values'][key] = 
            column_awareness_data_copy['product'].count()
        else:
            graph_data['values'][key] = 0
            df = pd.DataFrame(graph_data)
    df['label'] = df.index
    new_p = Bar(df, values='values', label='label', 
        legend=False, title='Sources Of Awareness', xlabel="", 
        ylabel="")
    layout.children[0].children[1] = new_p

def update_p2():
    global table_data_copy
    table_data_copy = table_data
    if income.value != 'All':
        table_data_copy = table_data_copy.loc[(table_data_copy['income_tier'] == income.value)]
    if age.value != 'All':
        table_data_copy = table_data_copy.loc[(table_data_copy['age'] == age.value)]
    if gender.value != 'All':
        table_data_copy = table_data_copy.loc[(table_data_copy['gender'] == gender.value)]
    if relationship.value != 'All':
        table_data_copy = table_data_copy.loc[(table_data_copy['relationship_label'] == relationship.value)]
    if education.value != 'All':
        table_data_copy = table_data_copy.loc[(table_data_copy['education_label'] == education.value)]
    if user_interests.value != 'All':
        table_data_copy = table_data_copy.loc[(table_data_copy[education.value] != None)]
    layout.children[1].children[0] = build_cross_table(question_1, question_2)

sizing_mode = 'fixed'
controls = [income, age, gender, relationship, education, user_interests]
for control in controls:
    control.on_change('value', lambda attr, old, new: update())
inputs = widgetbox(*controls, sizing_mode=sizing_mode)

p1 = initialize_graph(graph_data)
add_support_columns(question_1, question_2)
p2 = build_cross_table(question_1, question_2)
layout = layout([inputs, p1], [p2])
curdoc().add_root(layout)
curdoc().title = "hi-chew"
output_file("bar.html")

show(layout)
```

Here is how the page looks when it first loads:

[image]

Here is how it looks when I change the value of a Select:

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated.